# Ubuntu freezes, what's the shortcut to solve the memory leak problem?

Tags: freeze, ram

my Ubuntu recently freezes if I leave the desktop on for days.
I could simply resolve it with CTRL+F2 or ALT+F2 then type 'r' command.

Since Ubuntu 20 (not sure it's the version)
the 'r' doesn't exist anymore.

Is there a way to resolve my issue?

CTRL+ALT+BACKSPACE works but it closes all of my applications.
I want the solution to clear the memory leaks instead of close all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> possibility to restart Gnome Shell still exists in Ubuntu 20.04. However, as it always has been, this option only works **if you are running Gnome Shell on top of Xorg** instead of Wayland.

That it does not work for you may happen because you are running Ubuntu on Wayland. To change to an Xorg session, log out, then before logging back in, select the "Ubuntu on Xorg" session by clicking on the cog in the right bottom corner before logging back in.

Comment: Very strange, I never used Wayland, it won't let me log in because of my Nvidia or some driver issue, so I never was on Wayland, but "ubuntu" which I believe is xorg,
However, when I just re-logged, ALT+F2 looks different, it pops up in the center, when the previous session slide down from the top of the screen, when yes that dialog from the center is what i was looking for, and it works well now. Do you know what caused ALT+F2 slide down from the top of the screen, instead of pop-up in the center of the screen?

Comment: My answer may then not be applicable for your specific case, but it could be so I will leave it for future users. You are doing this in a memory full situation, so then things may act strange. Possibly, a next time it will work. So your issue probably is not due to the version as such, and one thing for sure that my answer states: in principle it is still there in Ubuntu 20.04.